# If $f$ is polynomial function prove there is $y$ such that $|f(y)| ≤ |f(x)|$ for every $x∈R$

Tags: polynomials

This question was translated and I don't know how to approach it.

If $f$ is polynomial function prove there is $y$ such that  $|f(y)| ≤ |f(x)|$ for every $x∈R$

(I think it's missing something).

Comment: The only thing that's missing, as far as I can see, is that you show us what you did to solve this problem. Besides, what has this problem to do with `infinitesimals`?

Comment: Ok, I removed infinitesimals

Answer (score 0):

If $p$ is a non constant polynomial, $lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}|p(x)|=\infty$.

There exists $N$ such that $|x|>N$ implies that $|p(x)|>|p(0)|$, since $|p$ is continuous, there exists $y\in [-N,N]$ such that for every $x\in [-N,N], |p(y)|\leq |p(x)|$. For every $x\in \mathbb{R}, |x|>N$ implies that $|p(y)|\leq |p(0)\leq |p(x)$, and if $|x|\leq N, |p(y)|\leq |p(x)$.